# Android how to capture shadow in screenshots

Tags: java, android, screenshot, shadow

How to capture shadow or elevation of views in the layout of the activity in a screenshots.This code take a screenshot for the view but it's not showing the shadow of the viewsenter image description here

```
View screenView = parentMain;
    screenView.buildDrawingCache();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getWidth() , screenView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    screenView.layout(0, 0, screenView.getLayoutParams().width, screenView.getLayoutParams().height);
    screenView.draw(c);
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    fakeImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Even if we add the harware acceleration at activity level it does not provides any effect.

Appreciate any alternative approaches
[image]

the result

[image]

Comment: Try to save your image in storage directory and then set that image to your image view.

Comment: see my answer sir hope this will help you out.

Comment: @commonsware Please help

Comment: got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
CardView card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);
```

Now just pass the card to captureScreenShot(). It returns the bitmap and save that bitmap saveImage().

You can pass any view Like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc any view can pass to captureScreenShot().

```
// Function which capture Screenshot
public Bitmap captureScreenShot(View view) {
    /*
     * Creating a Bitmap of view with ARGB_4444.
     * */
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable backgroundDrawable = view.getBackground();

    if (backgroundDrawable != null) {
        backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

// Function which Save image.
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File file = // Your Storage directory name + your filename
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally call this function like this.

```
saveImage(captureScreenShot(card));
```

Now set Your Image like this.

```
File file = new  File(“yourImageFilePath”);
if(file.exists())
{
    yourImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
}
```

Note : If setImageURI() not working then you can use below code.

```
File file = new  File(“yourImageFilePath”);
if(file.exists())
{
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString());
  yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```